# Manjaro won't boot after update, how to rescue?

Tags: grub, graphics, manjaro, troubleshooting

I ran `pacman -Syu` yesterday and seeing quite a few updates, walked away from the computer while it was doing its thing. When I came back the lock screen had come up, and I was surprised to find that I couldn't login despite entering my password. I should have probably tried switching to TTY but I didn't think of it.

I assumed that the problem would be resolved on a reboot and pressed the reset button. Now Manjaro refuses to boot. Specifically:

- I see the BIOS stuff as usual
- My drive is encrypted, so GRUB asks me for the passphrase as usual
- After decrypting, GRUB menu comes up
- If I choose any of the Manjaro boot options, I see the message from systemd displaying the version, and immediately after the screen starts flashing (looks like it's being turned off and on but the screen is always black)
- The HDD light also flashes occasionally
- At this point the computer is unresponsive and won't react to `Ctrl+Alt+1-7` for TTY or even `Ctrl+Alt+Del`. I have to hard reset to get out of it.

I am guessing the problem is bad video drivers. I think if I could somehow boot into Manjaro without launching my DE, Cinnamon, I could then tty to rerun the updates (maybe they had failed at some critical point), look at the logs or just tinker with the video drivers until I can get it to work again. However, currently all I have is the GRUB menu.

1. Is there something I can type in the GRUB command line (`c`) that will tell Manjaro to not load any video or GUI stuff?
2. Is there something I can do in the GRUB editor (`e`) to make the existing options boot without GUI?
3. Could I somehow use a liveCD to get into my installed Manjaro system and run commands from there? For instance if I `chroot`ed into my HD would I be able to just run `pacman -Syu`?

I have seen some recommendations online that suggest editing the GRUB menu and adding various parameters to the `linux` command, but my GRUB config file is apparently very complicated, and looks nothing like the examples I saw. I'd paste it here, but I'm not sure how to get it out of my computer. Also, I'm really confused about what keys to use in the GRUB editor.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd expect a livecd would be the most reliable as far as both finding the problem and solving it.

Comment: @Hatchet Right now I don't actually have access to a LiveCD (my USB is broken) so if possible I'd like to try any other options first. Also, it's not obvious to me what to actually do from the LiveCD, see #3 in my question.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not terribly experienced in working with bootloaders/grub, so I'll be of little help there, sorry. (I feel your pain, though!) Do you have more than one kernel installed atm? Trying to boot a different kernel might help.

Comment: This sounds like a GPU driver issue, with X trying to restart on fail repeatedly. Add `3` at the end of GRUB's boot line, then check `journalctl -b -1 -p err`. Then try `mhwd --help` for driver options. The Manjaro wiki has a section on this, as well.

Comment: @Mioriin adding `3`  to the line starting with `linux` and ending with `splash` dropped me in a working TTY. That's exactly what I needed, thank you! Wish I could upvote your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed [Mioriin's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356165/manjaro-wont-boot-after-update-how-to-rescue?noredirect=1#comment631166_356165) and pressed `e` at the GRUB prompt to edit the config. Then I found the line starting with `linux` and ending with `splash` and added a `3` to the end. Then I pressed F10 to boot.

This brought me to a textual TTY screen where I could enter my username/pass and was able to run CLI commands normally. I ran `pacman -Syu`, hoping that if I let it update itself successfully the problem would magically go away.

It appears that the python package `dateutils` was installed, and was causing pacman's update to fail. It seems that pacman tries to do big updates in a single transaction, to avoid partial update state due to interruptions, but despite this I think my system got borked by the update attempt.

I uninstalled `dateutils` with `pip uninstall python-dateutils`. Then I ran `pacman -Syu` again and it completed successfully. I ran `pacman -Syyu` just to make sure that the update was good, and it reported no out-of-date packages. I then also ran `pacaur -Syu` in the same fashion. After this I checked `dateutils` with `pip list` and it appears to have been installed back by the pacman update.

I rebooted and my computer, including GUI, worked as before.

Comment: I couldn't update my system, since the networking settings are not configured.How did you solved that issue?

Comment: @KevinRED Unfortunately I don't recall anymore whether it worked on its own or the first few things I tried got me working internet, but I had an ethernet connection so that might be part of it. In your case I would follow any online guide for networking on arch with CLI, and/or try an ethernet cable if possible.

Comment: Also you could boot from a livecd which *should* have working (or easily configurable) networking and chroot into your installed arch.

Comment: I did with chroot and it's working now. Thanks